# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'country_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel

I have two countries and states tables between them hasMany belongsTo relation.

I want to fill table states using seeder but it gives me this error:

> `'country_id' doesn't have a default value`

**StatesTableSeeder.php**

```
public function run()
    {
     $now = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(); 
     State::insert([ 
       ['name' =>'tihit','slug' =>'tihit','created_at'=> $now,'updated_at' =>$now],
    ])->countries()->attach(1); 
    }
```

Comment: Well I think that `country_id` doesn't have a default value.

Comment: so pass the `country_id` in the array of data you are inserting and remove everything after the `insert` method call ... and the `attach` method is only for `belongsToMany` relationships

Comment: thx for u answer but i think ])->countries()->attach(1); fill field country_id

Comment: you are not paying attention to what is happening here ... you are inserting data (that is a database INSERT statement) ... since you are not passing a `country_id` and there is no default on that field that is the error ... at the point of inserting that field MUST have a value, not after ... also you are not calling `create` you are calling `insert` which will not return a model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never defined a country in which you want to add a state. There are two ways of doing this:

1. Loop through all countries and then create a state for each of them

Get all the countries first:

```
$countries = Country::get(); //Assuming your model name is Country
$now = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
```

Loop them:

```
foreach ($countries as $country){
        State::insert([
            [
                'country_id' => $country->id,
                'name' =>'tihit',
                'slug' =>'tihit',
                'created_at'=> $now,
                'updated_at' =>$now
            ],
        ]);
    }
```

2. Add a state to a single (specific) country:

First find a specific country:

```
$country = Country::findOrFail($id); //Or use any other filter to find a single country
$now = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
```

Then add a state to that country

```
State::insert([
            [
                'country_id' => $country->id,
                'name' =>'tihit',
                'slug' =>'tihit',
                'created_at'=> $now,
                'updated_at' =>$now
            ],
        ]);
```

Comment: they could also just do this from the Country side `$country->states()->create(...)` and that would set the correct `country_id` and handle the timestamps

Comment: Agreed. You can edit my answer and add your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be to create this State record through the `states` relationship of Country:

```
$state = $country->states()->create([
    'name' => 'tihit',
    'slug' => 'tihit',
]);
```

This would set the `country_id` to that of `$country` and should set your timestamp fields for you as per normal with Eloquent.

Obviously assuming you setup the relationship from this side.